# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurs for updating table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

In order to update `Customer/PartyId` I asks the user to fill the `CP_id` and other elements of the form and then I update the data in database on the basis of `CP_id`:

```
if (CP_id.Text != " ")
{
    string cpid=CP_id.Text;
    string query = "Update tbl_partyinfo set Name = @Name, Addrss = @Addrss, Cntct_No = @Cntct_No where CP_id = cpid";

    using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        connection1.Open();

        using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection1)) 
        {
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtname.Text;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Addrss", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddrss.Text;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cntct_No", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcontact.Text;

            //make sure you open and close(after executing) the connection
            var rowsaffected = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection1.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Id no."+CP_id.Text +" Updated.");
         }
     }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please identify Id before updating");
}
```

But I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid column name 'cpid'

I am getting this error but have no substitute method to obtain such functionality.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining you inserting 3 parameters by proper binding and one by assuming "it just magically works". Why do you assume the cpid parameter works completely different than the other three?

Comment: @nvoigt  Updated the question code !   
But it now updates all the rows of table

Comment: Please don't change your question after getting an answer. If you have a new question, *ask a new question*.

Comment: @svick changed it to reflect, what i am suggested in the comments,was already given a try but of no worth.Anyways,i am done with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CP_id=cpid

This needs to be another bound paramameter like this: `CP_id=@cpid` and you need another line adding this parameter and it's value. You already did it for the other three, it cannot be too hard doing it for the fourth, too.

Comment: I already did try before posting it on SO but was affecting all the rows ,another disaster

Comment: "CP_id = @CP_id" this is really bad practice. If you miss a single @, you get a valid statement. You want an error if you make a mistake. Do not name your variables like your database fields.